# how to drop duplicate embedded document

Tags: mongodb, indexing, duplicates, mongodb-query

I have users' collection containing many lists of sub documents. Schema is something like this:

```
   {
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: aaa,
    age: 20,
    transactions:[
        {
         trans_id: 1,
         product: mobile,
         price: 30,
        },
        {
         trans_id: 2,
         product: tv,
         price: 10
        },
        ...]
    ...
   }
```

So I have one doubt. `trans_id` in `transactions` list is unique over all the products, but it may be possible that I may have copied the same transaction again with same `trans_id` (due to bad ETL programming). Now I want to drop those duplicate sub documents. I have indexed trans_id thought not `unique`. I read about `dropDups` option. But will it delete a particular duplicate exists in DB or it'll drop whole document (which I definitely don't want). If not how to do it?

PS: I am using MongoDB 2.6.6 version.

Comment: There is no possible index rule that would enforce 1 field of a document within an embedded array to be unique. The only possibiltity is bad code if that was the intent. If you want to "pull out" or modify the data so that is the applied rule then you can do so, but the question is what to do with the other documents in the array that share the same `trans_id`? It doesn't apply here, but for unique "documents" the `dropDups` option just arbitrarily removes documents, so even if it were applicable it usually is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearest case to all we can see presented here it that now you need a way of defining the "distinct" items within the array where some items are in fact an "exact copy" of other items in the array.

The best case is to use [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) along with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier within a looping operation for the collection. Ideally you use the  [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) to take advantage of the reduced traffic when doing so:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
var count = 0;

// Read the docs
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    // Blank the array
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc.id })
        .updateOne({ "$set": { "transactions": [] } });
    // Resend as a "set"
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc.id })
        .updateOne({ 
            "$addToSet": { 
                "trasactions": { "$each": doc.transactions }
            }
        });
    count++;

    // Execute once every 500 statements ( actually 1000 )
    if ( count % 500 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
    }
});

// If a remainder then execute the remaining stack
if ( count % 500 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

So as long as the "duplicate" content is "entirely the same" then this approach will work. If the only thing that is actually "duplicated" is the "trans_id" field then you need an entirely different approach, since none of the "whole documents" are "duplicated" and this means you need more logic in place to do this.